# How to send relative time to each sampler in JMeter JTL

Tags: jmeter

I see that JMeter's JTL file doesn't include the relative time (the time elapsed from test start time) in the JMeter JTL file.

Is there any system property I can include, or do I need to write a JSR223 post processor to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have this form of information it can be pretty easily calculated

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) at the same level as your [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def testStart = vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as Long
   def currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
   timeSinceTestStart = currentTime - testStart
   vars.put('timeSinceTestStart', timeSinceTestStart as String)
   ```
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=timeSinceTestStart
   ```
4. That's it, next time you run your JMeter test you .jtl file will contain an extra column called `timeSinceTestStart` with the value you're looking for.

References:

- [Pre-Defined Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops)
- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)